# Passing an operator to a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is it possible to pass an operator to a lambda?  For example passing some operator op to the function below.

`auto lambdaCompare = [](value,compare1,compare2,op){return value op compare1 and value op compare2;};`

Comment: you mean [`std::multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) and similar?

Comment: like if op was >= or <=.  Im trying to create a multi use lambda for comparison

Comment: For this case, you can pass a functor instead for op. Then in the body you can return op(value, compare1,compare2) or something similar.

Comment: [`std::greater_equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I would do this:

### C++14

```
auto l = [](auto value, auto c1, auto c2, auto op)
{
    return (op(value, c1) && op(value, c2));
};

l(1, 2, 3, [](int a, int b) { return a < b; });
```

### C++11

```
auto l = [](int value, int c1, int c2, bool(* op)(int, int))
{
    return (op(value, c1) && op(value, c2));
};

l(1, 2, 3, [](int a, int b) { return a < b; });
```

## Well, you could also do this:

I am conflicted whether or not to actually recommend this. On one hand it's a macro yuck, on the other hand it looks pretty innocent, it's simple and self-explanatory

### C++14

```
auto l = [](auto value, auto c1, auto c2, auto op)
{
    return (op(value, c1) && op(value, c2));
};

l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(<));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(<=));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(>));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(>=));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(==));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(!=));
```

with

```
#define OPERATOR(op) [] (const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a op b; }
```

### C++11

```
auto l = [](int value, int c1, int c2, Op_t<int, int, bool> op)
{
    return (op(value, c1) && op(value, c2));
};

l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, <));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, <=));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, >));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, >=));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, ==));
l(1, 2, 3, OPERATOR(int, int, !=));
```

with

```
#define OPERATOR(T1, T2, op) [] (const T1& a, const T2& b) { return a op b; }

template <class T1, class T2, class R>
using Op_t = auto (*) (const T1&, const T2&) -> R;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass an operator and then use it like you want but you can pass `std::greater_equal`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {

    auto lambdaCompare = [](int value, int compare1, int compare2, std::function<bool(int, int)> op) {
        return op(value, compare1) && op(value, compare2);
    };

    std::cout << lambdaCompare(2, 1, 6, std::greater_equal<int>());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you

Comment: Though, you *really* should prefer using a generic C++14 lambda and avoiding the overhead of `std::function` as you can (indirection leading to lack of inlining and / leading to destroyed chances for optimisation).

Comment: So would it be better to have one for std::greater_equal and one for std::less_equal.   Thus not having to send in an op

Answer (score 2):

In case your operators are free functions you could fallback to something like this

```
struct S
{
public:
    S(int i) : i (i) {}
    int i;
};

bool operator < (const S& s1, const S& s2)
{
    return s1.i < s2.i;
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda_compare = [](S s1, S s2, auto op) {
        return op(s1, s2);
    };
    bool b = lambda_compare(S(1), S(2), operator<);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better use a lambda, as the overload-set for `operator<` is rarely singular. And that avoids function-pointers, promoting inlining. Unfortunately generic lambdas made their debut in C++14 not C++11.